# Transparency issue with Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent

Tags: android

I have an activity which uses Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent. It's the only activity in my entire application that uses this theme. Im getting this weird issue/bug when returning to the previous activity. About 50% of the time it appears that the theme for the entire application gets messed up and random views all over the app become transparent.

I can sometimes switch the theme back to the correct one by going into the translucent activity and returning again

Has anyone encountered this before?

My theme's code is below:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorblue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did more testing and it seems to only be happening on lollipop