# appcompat-v7:23 breaking png transparency?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I had to upgrade my gradle file to use appcompat-v7:23.2.0, but it is breaking the png transparent pixels.

Before, my gradle looked like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    //etc...
```

and a screenshot of part of one of the fragments:

[image]

now I upgraded the gradle, making it look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    //etc...
```

but when I ran the code, I this is the resulting output of the same fragment:

[image]

and here part of the xml where I include these images where "@drawable/icon_uber" just points to the icon_uber.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:uber="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- a bunch of stuff -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_uber_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_uber" />
```

I looked at this thread:

[Transparency issue with Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.Translucent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230129/transparency-issue-with-theme-appcompat-noactionbar-translucent)

but no answer.

Anyone has a fix for this issue? I cannot go back to v7:22 since I have other dependencies that must use v7:23.

thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the portion of XML where you use the images?

Comment: Matei, I added a portion of the xml to the question. Not sure how the xml could be breaking it, but any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems ok to me. Neither I was convinced that xml could be the problem but double checking doesn't hurt.